# Add 'Zeros' in front of already existing number in my database

Tags: sql

I have the data table name as tblwcrates, in that I have as columns:

```
WC_code,wc_description,wc_rates
```

I almost complete all the process. Whenever I run my query, `wc_code` is in order but the maximum length of the digit is 5. In some cases where 2 & 3 digit numbers are there, I face the problems of illegal order. Example output:

```
0042
101
205
4094
16
```

I want to add leading zeros whenever i enter numbers that are less than 5 digits.

Comment: May I inquire why you store numbers as strings in the database?

Comment: In some cases i want add alphabatical with numbers.. Ex: 1025C

Comment: In that case, the solution of @Vijaykumar Hadalgi should satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Thank you  0xCAFEBABE.. Once I check with the below query let him know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
select RIGHT('0000000'+cast(wc_code as varchar(10),5)
```

Comment: Hi Vijaykumar Hadalgi, I import this query in my DB.. Bt it displayed all the rows as empty..

Comment: @ArunkumarMurugesan :: see this **[link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/defbe/2)** it works but i'm not sure about performance on large

Comment: Thank you so much Vijayakumar Hadalgi.. Now it works, i only made a mistake, once again thank you..

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you're ordering a string that contains a number. Instead of numerical sort, an alphabetical sort is used, while you're expecting numerical sort. Try

```
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(wc_code)
```

Alternatively, you can make sure your wc_code is padded with zeroes, either when converting from number to string (wc_code *is* a number in your table definition, right?) or afterwards. In Oracle, there's a function LPAD:

```
LPAD(wc_code, 5, '0')
```